# Is there a way to upload files in c++ using GridFS?

Tags: c++, mongodb, gridfs

I am working on uploading a file to MongoDB using the GridFS library but documentation seems to be sparse. Is there a way to read a file from a directory and upload the file into mongoDB?

```
int main(void)
{
  std::string database_name = "newdb";
  std::string collection_name = "new_collection";
  std::string mongodb_uri_address = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

  mongocxx::instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.
  mongocxx::uri uri(mongodb_uri_address);
  mongocxx::client client(uri);

  std::cout << "This should create the database mydb inside of MongoDB" << std::endl;
  mongocxx::database db = client["new"];
  mongocxx::collection coll = db["fs.files"];

  mongocxx::gridfs::bucket bucket = db.gridfs_bucket();
  auto uploader = bucket.open_upload_stream("sample_gridfs_file");

  // ASCII for "HelloWorld", this is the example provided by mongocxx drivers
  std::uint8_t bytes[10] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100};
  
  // read file and pass it to uploader.write
  uploader.write(bytes, 10);

  auto result = uploader.close();

  return 0;
}
```

The official [repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/gridfs.cpp) contains an example but it does not detail how to read a file and convert the file into the appropriate format to be stored in the MongoDB database according to the files and chunks convention GridFS adopts. Similar features are well documented in python and javascript but I can't seem to figure out or find a solution for c++

Comment: If it's a github repo, you can also raise an issue there and ask to include those details in the example code/docs.

Comment: For some reason the issues tab has been removed so I can't seem to raise an issue

Comment: I see a JIRA project for issues/bugs whose link is mentioned in the repo's README.